# How to make $\mathrm{Abs}[x + y\, I]^2$ produce $x^2 + y^2$?

Tags: complex

I want to get `x^2 + y^2` by evaluating `Abs[a + b I]^2`. Unfortunately, Mathematica just reproduces the same `Abs[a + b I]^2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand):

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[(x + y I)]^2]
```

> x^2 + y^2

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to be explicit about the domain of the variables, that is, that x and y are real valued:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(x + y I)]^2, Assumptions -> {x, y} \[Element] Reals]
x^2 + y^2
```